# Implementing a more 'wholistic' Context Menu in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out if my way of implementing a Context-Menu in ReactJS is the 'React' way of things (or perhaps a more advanced way) or perhaps i'm wrong.

I have an page which resembles a 'windows file explorer' (part of a very large web-app)
three main areas:
- Left Pane: Folder tree
- Right Pane: Folder Grid & below it File List
Everything is a component, from the TreeView to the File/Folder.

Each 'leaf' component (items on the tree, files in the file-list and folder in the 'folder-grid') require a 'Context Menu' opened by an ellipsis button (not right click).

Our FE stack is ReactJS, Redux & Saga

I know the straight-forward way would be to just implent a ContextMenu (perhaps a generic one) component to each of these components in it's render - but i was wondering about a more 'whole' approach to a ReactJS system design.

As there are many objects across the page that require a Context Menu I got into thinking it might be a better solution to have a wrapper component in the application from which components could request a ContextMenu to be drown.
the request would be a JSON object, with an array of 'context actions' - each has a name, icon and function to invoke.

Providing a component with this so called ability to request context menu can be done with redux or simply pushing down the component tree a method (well - preferably not)

So - implementing a declarative, system-wide context menu 'service' in ReactJS - a sound architecture decision or am I a bad React programmer :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an entirely reasonable thing to do.  In fact, my post [Practical Redux, Part 10: Managing Modals and Context Menus](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/) demonstrates almost this exact approach.  The one big difference is that to stay consistent with Redux's principle of "all actions should be serializable", I don't include callbacks functions in the action objects.  Instead, I provide a "result action" object that the dialog can fill in.  If you *really* want to include a callback function in the action you can, but it will likely cause time-travel debugging to work incorrectly, and it's not considered idiomatic Redux usage.

Comment: this is pretty funny - I based my initial thoughts and research based on that specific post - sorry I didn't gave credit where credit is due !